# How to understand why massive fields decay exponentially with distance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, mass, field-theory, propagator

I have read and heard numerous times that a vector field in nonabelian gauge theory which has gained mass through the Higgs mechanism decreases in strength exponentially with distance as it propagates. I would be thankful for a brief explanation of the approach and result and, if possible, a reference for a thorough treatment.

My attempt:

I expected to find evidence for this behavior in the massive vector boson propagator which can be written in the unitary gauge

$$
\frac{g_{\mu \nu} - k_{\mu} k_{\nu}/m^2}{k^2-m^2}.
$$

I would like Fourier transform this to position space, so I integrate the following term by term

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{g_{\mu \nu} - k_{\mu} k_{\nu}/m^2}{k^2-m^2} e^{2\pi i k_{\mu}x^{\mu}} d^4k.
$$

I have three types of terms to integrate:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2-a^2} e^{2\pi i kx} dk
$$

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k^2-a^2} e^{2\pi i kx} dk
$$

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{k^2}{k^2-a^2} e^{2\pi i kx} dk
$$

But I get divergences in these integrals and I am unsure where to go next.

Comment: This has nothing to do with (non-Abelian) gauge theory, you're just trying to compute that the force mediated by a massive vector boson has a [Yukawa potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential)., and you seem to just ask for who to solve these integrals, which would appear off-topic per our [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: My interest is not specifically in solving the integrals, but in the method/approach to showing the exponential decay of the massive components of the gauge field. I wrote what I'd done so far in seeking the answer via one approach to show that I've been thinking about the problem, but I would like to understand the general principle. FWIW, this is not for homework, I am studying the topic as background and want to understand conceptually the origin of the exponential decay of massive components of gauge fields. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica will make fairly short work of these integrals.  Or they can be looked up in a field theory text book.  I believe, for example, that the Fourier transform of $1/(k^2+m^2)$ is discussed in connection with scalar fields and the Klein-Gordon equation in the first few chapters of Peskin and Schroeder, at least in a Lorentzian setting.

Why the Fourier transform of this propagator is related to the Yukawa potential in the first place is a different question.  If I were to try to derive it, I would calculate tree level exchange of a massive vector in field theory.  Then I would try to figure out what potential in the Born approximation in non-relativistic quantum mechanics would lead to the same scattering.  A slightly different answer is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69834/coulomb-potential/69845#69845).

Let's start with the first integral
$$
I = \int d^4k \frac{e^{i k\cdot x}}{k^2 + m^2} \ .
$$
Note I have flipped the sign of the $m^2$ term.  This is because I want to do the integral in Euclidean signature.  I can adapt the $k$-coordinate system so that $x$ points in the polar or "$z$''-direction.  I can then break up the measure factor in spherical coordinates
$$
d^4 k = k^3 dk \, \sin^2 \theta d \theta \, d \Omega_2 \ .
$$
The last $d\Omega_2$ is the measure on an $S^2$ with unit radius.  As nothing depends on these angles, they will integrate to give $4 \pi$.  Let's focus on the $\theta$ integral.  Mathematica tells us
$$
\int_0^\pi e^{i k x \cos \theta} \sin^2 \theta \, d \theta = \frac{\pi}{kx} J_1(kx) \ .
$$
Mathematica will also handle the final $k$-integral
$$
I =  \frac{4 \pi^2 m}{x} K_1(m x) \ .
$$
If we expand out the Bessel-K function for large argument, we find the desired exponential behavior
$$
I = e^{-m x} \left( \pi^{5/2} m^{1/2} \left(\frac{2}{x} \right)^{3/2} + O(x^{-2}) \right) \ .
$$

A trick for the $k_\mu k_\nu$ integral is that it can be obtained by taking $x$ derivatives of the first integral.  But this will give a similar exponentially damped behavior at large $x$.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful with the integrals. May you be more specific about the appendix or section in Peskin and Schroeder that discusses the massive vector propogator in the spatial representation? I would appreciate being able to read a full discussion in an educational text.

I was not able to find/recognize a discussion of this in P&S's six short appendices, nor in the sections
20.1 (Higgs Mechanism; non Abelian examples), 
Chapter 21: Quantization of Spontaneously Broken Gauge Theories 
21.1: $R_{\xi}$ Gauges, non Abelian analysis, or 
21.3: Vacuum Polarization Amplitudes.

Comment: I don't have P&S with me right now, and you are probably right, come to think of it, that they do the integrals in the appendices without the $e^{ikx}$ factor.

Comment: Could you list a reference that deals in detail (or cite a place in P&S) with the exponential behavior of the massive vector field as it propagates? Is this behavior usually derived from the propagator, as you showed above, or is it typically shown from the field equations themselves more directly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The standard trick I know is to think about a tree level exchange process in field theory between two charged objects that involves the massive vector boson.  Then one asks, for the corresponding process in non-relativistic quantum mechanics, what potential would produce a similar scattering using the Born approximation.  This comparison, at leading order, boils down to taking a Fourier transform of the propagator.  For a photon, this calculation is I believe discussed in Landau and Lifshitz relativistic quantum mechanics.  But adding a mass to the photon shouldn't change things much.