# EMF induced in a dynamo is by photons of permanent magnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, virtual-particles

i know little about the quantum field theory and also that the permanent magnets have there fields because of exchange of virtual photons across or around the ends. so when we take a dynamo and the constantly changing magnetic field and the emf thus produced, is it possible that it is due to the virtual photons of the magnetic field.

Please correct me if I am wrong and please explain the QFT also if possible and veeeerrrryyyy simply please.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3580/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2244/2451 and links therein.

Comment: nope not a duplicate they are not telling anything about the emf produce in a coil due to changing magnetic field